# Consecutive Visits

Tags: support, badges

I was on Mi Yodeya every day this past week or so and I just went to look at how many days I have been on consecutively and it says 1. How is this possible? Am I missing something?

Comment: Were you on the site on July 13 (Saturday) based on UTC?  (I don't know what timezone you're in, so you might have had a small window in which to do that not on Shabbat.)

Comment: I was on after Shabbat

Comment: And after Shabbat was before midnight UTC?  (I don't know what timezone you're in.)

Comment: I visited the site after Shabbat, before midnight, Eastern Time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stack Exchange time is counted by UTC ([Coordinated Universal Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)), which is (currently) four hours ahead of US Eastern.  You visited the site after Shabbat on Saturday (July 13 where you and I live), but that would have already been July 14 UTC.  Unless you visited the site on Friday shortly before Shabbat (after midnight UTC, so July 13 in Stack Exchange time), you missed the day.  Confusing, I know.

See [Is it possible to earn the Fanatic badge halachically?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7594/472) for more information.

Comment: Thanks! So what time does a day "start" where I live on Mi Yodeya?

Comment: If you're in US Eastern, currently 8PM (7PM in standard time).  If you hover over your name at the top of any page on the site, you'll see a panel with your recent votes, rep changes, badges, etc -- at the bottom of that is the current time in UTC.

Comment: Thanks again! This helps a lot

Comment: You're welcome.  The answers to the question I linked explain more about how this is done (including a little about what counts as a visit).